# Sending image from Android to App Engine endpoint

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

I am using App Engine's cloud endpoint and I have an Android client. I am able to do everything correctly except sending an image from the Android client to the endpoint.

I am using BytesField for my endpoint, but in Android, it is shown as String (the params only accept String). I have a Drawable in my phone and I want to send it over.

```
    REGISTER_RESOURCE = endpoints.ResourceContainer(
            message_types.VoidMessage,
            username=messages.StringField(1, variant=messages.Variant.STRING, required=True),
            password=messages.StringField(2, variant=messages.Variant.STRING, required=True),
            email=messages.StringField(3, variant=messages.Variant.STRING, required=True),
            phone=messages.StringField(4, variant=messages.Variant.STRING, required=True),
            gender=messages.StringField(5, variant=messages.Variant.STRING, required=True),
            location=messages.StringField(6, variant=messages.Variant.STRING, required=True),
            picture=messages.BytesField(7, variant=messages.Variant.BYTES)
            )

    @endpoints.method(REGISTER_RESOURCE, LoginUser,
                      path='register', http_method='POST',
                      name='login.register')
    def validate_register(self, request):
        ...
```

I have tried converting my Drawable to a String by doing this:

```
        // convert image to byte array and encode to base 64
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) photo).getBitmap();
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        byte[] bitmapData = stream.toByteArray();
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(bitmapData, Base64.DEFAULT);
        validateRegister.setPicture(encodedImage);
```

But it doesn't work. I tried looking at the value of encodedImage and it is a very long string.

I plan to get the Drawable over from Android to the server and then store it in the datastore (db.Model) BlobProperty.

Comment: why dont you use json? and add the base64 encoded image as a value in the object?